# I can't rename my transaction on HP Virtual User Generator Script

Tags: testing, performance-testing, loadrunner

I've copied Vu's Script, (and of course renamed it) which have access to another DB, and when I run it I have in the output the old transaction name of the old script.

here is the old transaction name which are to seen in the output : **MDM_GetAssociations** 
Here is the renamed transaction:**MDM_GET_ASSOCIATIONS_Otmann**

After renaming the transaction, I run the script, I got 2 errors:
1)
Error   14  undeclared identifier `MDM_GET_ASSOCIATIONS_Otmann' Action.c    C:\GCDM_Test\Scripts\MDM\MDM_Get_POSTGRE_Otmann MDM_Get_POSTGRE_Otmann

2)
Error   15  type error in argument 1 to `web_custom_request'; found`int' expected `pointer to const char'  Action.c    C:\GCDM_Test\Scripts\MDM\MDM_Get_POSTGRE_Otmann MDM_Get_POSTGRE_Otmann

and this is my script :

```
//########## start the test scenario ############
web_set_max_html_param_len("8000");
web_set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION", "TLS");
web_add_auto_header("Content-Type","application/xml");
web_add_auto_header("Accept","application/json");
web_add_auto_header("Authorization",lr_eval_string("{AUTHORIZATION}"));

//GetAssociations, NOTE: our dummy customers have often NO associations!
web_reg_save_param("RESPONSE", "LB=", "RB=", "Search=Body", LAST);
lr_start_transaction((char*)MDM_GENERIC_TRANSACTION);
lr_start_transaction((char*)MDM_GET_ASSOCIATIONS);
web_custom_request(MDM_GET_ASSOCIATIONS, 
    "URL={TEST_ENV_HOSTNAME}/api/v3/clients/{BUSINESS_CONTEXT}/customers/{GCID}/associations",
    "Method=GET", 
    "Resource=1",   // => We are retrieving a ressource, 
                    // which implies that it is not critical for the success of the script. 
                    // Any failures (HTTP 404 - Not found etc.) in downloading the resource 
                    // will be considered as warnings rather than errors.
    "EncType=application/xml", 
    "Referer=Loadrunner",
    LAST);
lr_end_transaction((char*)MDM_GET_ASSOCIATIONS, LR_AUTO);
lr_end_transaction((char*)MDM_GENERIC_TRANSACTION, LR_AUTO);

return 0;
```

}

and this is the output where the old transaction name apeared (MDM_GetAssociations), but I don't know where is she coded or from where she came, and as I said before when I try to change it in all position which has to do with Transactions,I got the errors mentioned above.

Here ist the output of the script, where you can see the name of the old the transaction(MDM_GetAssociations).

```
    Action.c(13): Notify: Transaction "MDM_GenericServiceCall_ALL" started.
    Action.c(14): Notify: Transaction "MDM_GetAssociations" started.
    Action.c(15): web_custom_request("MDM_GetAssociations") started 
    Action.c(15): web_custom_request("MDM_GetAssociations") highest severity level was "warning", 505 body bytes, 1971 header bytes     [MsgId: MMSG-26388]
    Action.c(25): Notify: Transaction "MDM_GetAssociations" ended with "Pass" status (Duration: 1,8408 Wasted Time: 1,2668).
    Action.c(26): Notify: Transaction "MDM_GenericServiceCall_ALL" ended with "Pass" status (Duration: 2,4066 Wasted Time: 1,2668).
    Ending action Action.
    Ending iteration 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two variables.  You do not have their declarations here.  You do not have their contents.   And you appear to be casting them from another data type to a pointer to a character.

Does this pass with a literal, "My_Test_Transaction"?  If so, then you are likely looking at oddities on how your variable is declared, populated and referenced.